# Show ticks on x axis in local time with highcharts api

Tags: highcharts

I have a line chart with a date/time x axis. The points have a name that is converted to local time. However, the tick marks are placed at UTC midnight. How can I get them to be placed at local midnight?

To clarify, my localtime is EDT (-04:00). So, at approximately 20:00, the tick mark is shown.

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  "chart": {
    "type": "line",
    "height": 300,
    "marginLeft": 60,
    "marginRight": 0,
    "spacingLeft": 0,
    "spacingRight": 0,
    "style": {
      "fontSize": 14
    },
    "zoomType": "x"
  },
  "tooltip": {
    "pointFormat": "{point.y}",
    "style": {
      "fontSize": 14
    }
  },
  "exporting": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "title": {
    "text": "",
    "style": {
      "display": "none"
    }
  },
  "subtitle": {
    "text": "",
    "style": {
      "display": "none"
    }
  },
  "legend": {
    "enabled": "false"
  },
  "xAxis": {
    "type": "datetime",
    "labels": {
      "enabled": true,
      "style": {
        "fontSize": "12px"
      }
    },
    "title": {
      "text": null
    },
    "minTickInterval": 86400000
  },
  "plotOptions": {
    "line": {
      "color": "#33aaee",
      "step": "true",
      "lineWidth": 1
    }
  },
  "credits": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "series": [{
    "data": [{
      "x": 1499935040582,
      "y": 600.8919674194846,
      "name": "Jul 13, 2017 4:37 AM"
    }, {
      "x": 1500069665426,
      "y": 600.3026594460489,
      "name": "Jul 14, 2017 6:01 PM"
    }, {
      "x": 1500133689471,
      "y": 600.7274040373635,
      "name": "Jul 15, 2017 11:48 AM"
    }, {
      "x": 1500197550895,
      "y": 600.1197607401385,
      "name": "Jul 16, 2017 5:32 AM"
    }, {
      "x": 1500224766324,
      "y": 600.2311428390589,
      "name": "Jul 16, 2017 1:06 PM"
    }, {
      "x": 1500247544551,
      "y": 600.5511455212492,
      "name": "Jul 16, 2017 7:25 PM"
    }, {
      "x": 1500282216949,
      "y": 600.2677789206001,
      "name": "Jul 17, 2017 5:03 AM"
    }, {
      "x": 1500285249151,
      "y": 600.3165520296044,
      "name": "Jul 17, 2017 5:54 AM"
    }, {
      "x": 1500472917987,
      "y": 600.6858600814295,
      "name": "Jul 19, 2017 10:01 AM"
    }, {
      "x": 1500479945476,
      "y": 600.6974345877289,
      "name": "Jul 19, 2017 11:59 AM"
    }],
    "showInLegend": false,
    "allowPointSelect": true
  }]
});
```

Here is a fiddle showing this.
[Highcharts fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8vwdd74o/1/)

Comment: For local time set global.useUTC to false. See API for details and more options http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/global.useUTC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer to my problem. I am using moment.js to format the time data, so I changed it from:

```
chart.series[0].data.push({ x: moment(grp.Time).format('x'), 
    y: grp.DoubleValue, name: moment(grp.Time).format(this.config.get('momentFullDateTimeFormat')) });
```

to:

```
chart.series[0].data.push({ x: moment(grp.Time).utc(true).format('x'), 
    y: grp.DoubleValue, name: moment(grp.Time).format(this.config.get('momentFullDateTimeFormat')) });
```

So basically I added the ".utc(true)" to the moment definition for the x value.

Answer (score 0):

Change you epoch's to a javascript date [new Date(epoch)] this will have the date/time fields show in local time instead of UTC.

```
"series": [{
    "data": [{
      "x": new Date(1499935040582),
      "y": 600.8919674194846
    }, {
      "x": new Date(1500069665426),
      "y": 600.3026594460489
    }, {
      "x": new Date(1500133689471),
      "y": 600.7274040373635
    }, {
      "x": new Date(1500197550895),
      "y": 600.1197607401385
    }, {
      "x": new Date(1500224766324),
      "y": 600.2311428390589
    }, {
      "x": new Date(1500247544551),
      "y": 600.5511455212492
    }, {
      "x": new Date(1500282216949),
      "y": 600.2677789206001
    }, {
      "x": new Date(1500285249151),
      "y": 600.3165520296044
    }, {
      "x": new Date(1500472917987),
      "y": 600.6858600814295
    }, {
      "x": new Date(1500479945476),
      "y": 600.6974345877289
    }],
```

This should keeps your chart in scale with your local time zone

Comment: I've updated my jsfiddle to use this without any change. I made the second point July 15th at midnight and you can plainly see that the tick is now 4 hours ahead (in my timezone). I also tried setting global.useUTC to false (and to true) per morganfree's comment, and it made no difference. http://jsfiddle.net/8vwdd74o/2/

Comment: you need to remove the name property from your data series which you hadnt updated your fiddle too.